# How can i test my Outlook web add-in during the meeting schedule

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am creating a Outlook web add-in, When i am running it it can be accessed in email detail at 3 dot menu. but how can i get and test same web add-ins in sandbox when i book meeting from outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Selenium` with adapters to automate web browsers and desktop applications. You may find the [Selenium WebDriver Tutorial : Getting Started with Test Automation](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-webdriver-tutorial#:%7E:text=Selenium%20WebDriver%20is%20a%20web,language%20to%20create%20test%20scripts.) page helpful.